# Cloud build trigger should not create the docker image based on git commit message

Tags: google-cloud-platform, continuous-integration, google-cloud-build, cloudbuild.yaml

If a user commits a code with the commit message "skip-docker-creation" so the cloud build pipeline should not create the docker image how we can achieve this in the pipeline ?

Answer (score 0):

This is solved I am putting the cloud build code here for everyone.

steps:

- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/git'
  entrypoint: 'bash'
  args: [ '-c', 'commit_message=$(git log --format=%B -n 1) && echo "${commit_message}" > /workspace/commitmessage.txt']
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  entrypoint: 'bash'
  args:

  - '-c'
  - |
    echo "Then we saved" $(cat /workspace/commitmessage.txt)

    if [ "$(cat /workspace/commitmessage.txt)" != "skip-docker-creation" ]; then
    docker build -t 'gcr.io/xyzgration/1ykybaj0879c22' .
    else
    exit 0;
    fi